# No argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'name' of 'Person.Person(string, string, int)'

Tags: c#

I get the following error:

> No argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter
>   'name' of 'Person.Person(string, string, int)'

Why is it showing error CS7036 at line 'class student : person' in my code below? Please explain?

```
class Person
{   
    public string Name = "";
    public string Occupation = "";
    public int Age = 20;

    public Person(string name, string occupation, int age) 
    {
        Name = name; 
        Occupation = occupation;
        Age = age; 
    }
}

class Student : Person
{
    public bool HasCup = false;

}

class CanteenBoardMember : Student
{
 public static int CupBudget = 100;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a homework, you'll have to inherit the base constructor of `Person` in `Student` class

Comment: We need to see the actual code that is producing this error, wherever you are calling `new Person(....)`. Cant help you with just the models. Somewhere you are calling `new Person()` without the arguments. If you only have constructors that require arguments then you have to supply them.

Comment: sing System;

namespace DIKUCanteen
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Canteen c = new Canteen("",5); 
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
    }
}

Comment: using System;

namespace DIKUCanteen
{    
    class Room
    {
        public string Name = "";
        
        public Room(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }}

Comment: Your `Student` class needs to define a constructor that calls the constructor of the base class `Person(name, occupation, age)`.

Comment: example? i have tried, but none of them works?

Comment: @YoungT Edit the question with your attempted code and what error so that we may find how you implemented it wrong.

Comment: i have? the title is the error, and the attempted code is written?

Comment: @YoungT in your last comment you wrote "i have tried, but none of them works?" - the question i linked *is* the solution, so if it didn't work, it was implemented incorrectly. I request that you add how you attempted *that* solution so we can identify the new problem.

Comment: Klaycon is correct, the suggested duplicate answers the question.  My answer provides a concrete example of how to implement it for your specific case.  If it doesn't work or you have errors then please add details and clarify the question.

Comment: It worked haldo!

Comment: Thank you all. Haldo and Klaycon!

Comment: @YoungT Congrats! Remember to accept haldo's answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The base class (`Person`) doesn't have a parameter-less constructor.  When you create an instance of `Student`, the compiler doesn't know how to create the base class `Person` (which `Student` inherits from) because there is no default (parameter-less) constructor.

That means you need to call the base class constructor from the derived class when it is instantiated.

```
class Student : Person
{
    // constructor
    public Student(string name, string occupation, int age) : base (name, occupation, age)
    {
        ...
    }

    public bool HasCup = false;    
}
```

And similarly for `CanteenBoardMember` class.